# slf4j MDC doesn`t print value in console

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j

i can`t manage to simple print log from MDC key value
nothing show up on any of my log not sure what configuration i am missing. Does anybody have a hint?

here my filter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String MDCData = String.format("[idDm=%s]",Util.getIdDm((HttpServletRequest)request));
        MDC.put("mdcData", MDCData);
        fc.doFilter(request, response);
    }finally {
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```

here application.yml have this

```
logging:
  pattern: '%X{mdcData}%5p'
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.stream.HystrixStreamTask: FATAL
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try put your pattern under `logging.pattern.level` like this

```
logging:
  pattern:
    level: '%X{mdcData}%5p'
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.stream.HystrixStreamTask: FATAL
```